# Run python from R via system command

Tags: python, r, command-line

I want to execute python code from R via the `system2` function, which invokes a command line.

Here is an example:

```
mcar = R6::R6Class(
  public = list(
    initialize = function() {
      system2("python -c", "import gym; env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')")
    },
    reset = function() {
      system2("python -c", "env.reset()")
    }
    getActionSpace = function() {
      system2("python -c", "env.action_space")
    }
  )
)

a = mcar$new()
a$reset()
a$getActionSpace()
```

`a = mcar$new()` should create the gym environment and then it should be possible to call `a$reset()` or `a$getActionSpace()`. Because I do not know in advance in which order `reset` and `getActionSpace` will be called, I cannot just write a python script and call this, e.g.

```
import gym
env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')
env.reset()
env.action_space
```

But `system2("python -c", "import gym; env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')")` returns an error:

> running command '"python -c" import gym; env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')' had status 127

Comment: You can write it to file and then read or just try `python -c "x=1; x+1"`

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? If you're planning to input multiple commands, start an interactive session.

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe I should have added more details, but I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible... So I take from your answers that this is not possible? No I don't want to use a file because I want to call python commands from an external program by invoking a system command and I do not know in advance the order of the calls. I will edit the post to make it more clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't put all the commands in a python script and then just call that from the command line?

```
python example.py
```